# How to update a many to many relationship in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to update a many to many relationship between two models in my API. I have `Teacher` and `Student` models.

I can add a `Student` to `Teacher`, like so in my `teachers_controller.rb`:

```
...
def update
  @teacher = Teacher.find(params[:id])
  if teacher_params[:student_id]
    @student = Student.find(teacher_params[:student_id])
    @teacher.students << @student
  end
  @teacher.save
  render json: @teacher, include: 'students', status: :ok
end
...
```

However, let's say I want to remove a student's relationship to a teacher, how can I do this? The only way I can think of doing this is finding a student, then iterating over the array of a teacher's students and removing the match, but not entirely sure about this method. Is there a better way?

Comment: If Teacher and Student have a Many to Many relationship I don't see why your `update` only handles adding a student to the array. your form should be sending an array of student_ids not just one and then simply do `@teacher.students = teacher_params[:student_ids]`

Comment: have you tried `@teacher.studers.where(id: some_id).destroy` ?

Comment: Perhaps you should show your models with their associations.

Comment: Thanks @fanta - I believe this is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller try this:

```
def update
 @teacher = Teacher.new(parameters)
 if params.has_key?(:students)

    @teacher.students.clear #this removes the reference to all previous students. 
    params[:students].each do |i|
        @teacher.students << Student.find(i)
    end
 end
 @teacher.save!
end
```

In your edit view, you could show a list of check boxes like so:

```
<% @students.each do |i| %>                  
      <li class="list-group-item">
            <%= check_box_tag "students[]", i.id, @teacher.student_ids.include?(i.id) %>
            <%= i.name %>
      </li>
<% end %>
```

You would just put this code inside of your form somewhere. Make sure you set `@students` and `@teacher` in your `edit` function in your controller.

Hope this helps.

NOTE: the reason I chose to find each student before adding them to the student/teacher reference and deleting every student/teacher ref on each update request was due to maintaining a security feature that I used in a app I recently created. For my case I was finding records associated under a certain account. You could also save the references like @jwoodrow said in the comments.